# how can i change the labels of the filtered objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to filter the data from the array of objects which is nicely done, but i want to change labels how can i do those, here is how my code look alike

```
let items = this.mydata;
          let aSelectedData = [];
          const aAcceptedKeys = ["billingAcc", "System"];
          aSelectedData = items.map(function (v, k) {
          let nestedObjects = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < aAcceptedKeys.length; i++) {
            let k = i;
            let v1 = aAcceptedKeys[k];
              if (typeof v[v1] != 'undefined') {
                nestedObjects[v1] = v[v1];
              }
            }
            return Object.assign({}, nestedObjects);
          });
```

i want the labels to be : `bill` and `invoice` instead of `billingAcc` and `System`

code added above with what i have tried till now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is sanitised (all items are objects and they all have `billingAcc` and `System`), the shortest syntax would be:

```js
const prettyData = myData.map(({ billingAcc: bill, System: invoice }) => ({
  bill,
  invoice
}))
```

Test:

```js
const myData = Array.from({ length: 10 }).map((_, key) => ({
  billingAcc: `Bill ${key + 1}`,
  System: `Invoice ${key + 101}`
}))

const prettyData = myData.map(({ billingAcc: bill, System: invoice }) => ({
  bill,
  invoice
}))

console.log(prettyData)
```

---

If you want to filter the items that don't have either `billingAcc` or `System` and you don't want `bill` or `invoice` to be set to `undefined` in the resulting items if they didn't exist on the raw data, this would work:

```js
const isDefined = (item) => item !== undefined
const prettyData = myData
  .filter(({ billingAcc, System }) => [billingAcc, System].some(isDefined))
  .map(({ billingAcc: bill, System: invoice }) =>
    Object.assign(
      {},
      isDefined(bill) ? { bill } : {},
      isDefined(invoice) ? { invoice } : {}
    )
  )
```

Test:

```js
const myData = [
  { billingAcc: '1', System: 'foo' },
  { billingAcc: '2', System: 'bar' },
  { foo: 'Skipped, no billingAcc or System' },
  { billingAcc: '' },
  { System: null },
  { billingAcc: 0 },
  { System: NaN },
  { billingAcc: void 0 } // void 0 === undefined, should be skipped
]
const isDefined = (item) => item !== undefined
const prettyData = myData
  .filter(({ billingAcc, System }) => [billingAcc, System].some(isDefined))
  .map(({ billingAcc: bill, System: invoice }) =>
    Object.assign(
      {},
      isDefined(bill) ? { bill } : {},
      isDefined(invoice) ? { invoice } : {}
    )
  )

console.log(prettyData)
```